# AWS S3 Usage Limit : How to reduce usage?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, heroku

I have nearly reached my AWS S3 usage limit for the month, after having started it just a couple of weeks ago, and I'm trying to understand why. I've never used AWS before, and I'm a newb in general. I literally have 3 jpegs in storage, nothing else.

Is usage solely determined by hours? I read that hours are instances where the storage is made available. Right now I have the Django project hosted on Heroku with media on AWS. I am very much still in dev mode, and only need AWS when testing project on Heroku, but most of the time I'm in local environment. Given that, I am confused how my usage limit could be nearly reached within a couple of weeks. Any guidance is appreciated.

**Update:** I was mistaken. The account number listed in the warning email is the same used for my AWS S3, but **it is referring instead to RDS**. When I see all products under the account it shows S3 (which is well below the limit) and RDS (which is nearly at the limit). The quandary now though is that I never intended to create an RDS instance. And, when I click on "databases" under RDS, it actually says I don't have any RDS instances. So I don't have RDS yet I do because I am soon to be charged for going over the limit. I've never used AWS before, and I'm a newb in general. I initiated S3, the only product I intended to have under the account, for the sole purpose of serving media files not served by Heroku.

Comment: S3's pricing is based on total storage ($$/GB/month) and requests ($$/GET/month and $$/PUT/month). The free tier (for first 12 months) is 5GB of total storage (sounds like you're nowhere near this), 20,000 get requests, and 2,000 put requests. Is it possible your project is making more requests than this?

Comment: @AlexGrounds I suppose it is possible, but I don't see how. My project is super small and I'm the only user. This is why I am confused how I could be nearly at my usage limit.

Comment: @Zuckerbrenner Please edit your question to include the _details_ of your usage -- for example, provide the information that says that you are close to your usage limit. This will help us interpret what it means (eg whether it is for storage, requests or Data Transfer).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I updated the question. I am sorry for the confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In the AWS management console:

- Click your username (in the top-right, to the left of the Region name)
- Select **My Billing Dashboard**
- Click **Bill Details** in the top-right

This will give you a breakdown of costs by service and region.

It is possible that your Amazon RDS instance is running in a different region, so find the region where the RDS costs are occurring and:

- Go to Amazon RDS in the management console
- Change the Region in the top-right to the one that was shown in the billing console
- Delete the database (if you are sure you aren't using it)

Comment: No databases appeared, but your answer was helpful regardless. Thank you.